# Why can I not use std::cin.getline() twice in succession?

Tags: c++, istream

Only the first call to `getline()` appears to read anything in from `std::cin`. Is the fact that `buffer` contains something a problem - why doesn't `getline()` just overwrite the contents of `buffer`?

How can I get the second call to `getline()` to read something in?

My code:

```
const int recordLen = 20;

// truncate the input to 20 chars
void getText(char line[])
{
  std::cout << "Enter something for getText: ";
  std::cin.getline(line, recordLen+1);
  for(int i = std::strlen(line); i < recordLen; i++)
  {
    line[i] = ' ';
  }
  line[recordLen] = '\0';
}

int main()
{
  char buffer[340];
  getText(buffer);

  std::cout << buffer;

  std::cout << "Now enter some more text:";

  // put more text into buffer
  std::cin.getline(buffer, 30);
  std::cout << "you entered : " << buffer << std::endl;
  return 0;
}
```

So - example output of program:

Enter something for getText: alskdjfalkjsdfljasldkfjlaksjdf
   alskdjfalkjsdfljasldNow enter some more text:you entered :

After the display of "Now enter some more text:", the program immediately displays "you entered:". It does not give me the opportunity to enter more text, neither does it display any characters that were truncated from the previous call to getline().

Comment: Can you show what input you give it?

Comment: `getline` does overwrite the contents of `buffer`. I tested your code and it works as expected. Your problem must be something else.

Comment: @john, did you enter more than `recordLen` chars on the first request for input? If I do this, the second call to `getline()` appears to get skipped, or not allow me to input anything.

Comment: @BeeBand Not but Alex has answered that question. You would avoid this problem if you used std::string instead of char arrays.

Comment: I don't think he has answered the question of why those characters that remain in the cin stream after the first call to `getline()`, do not get displayed after the second call to `getline()`.

Comment: @john ... why would the problem be avoided using strings?

Comment: @BeeBand because strings have no limits on their size, so `std::string line; getline(std::cin, line);` will always read the whole line.

Comment: @BeeBand chars remain in the stream because that's just the definition of getline, makes more sense than ignoring data.

Comment: @BeeBand On the second point, if you enter too many characters it is considered an error on the stream, and that causes all subsequent operations on `std::cin` to fail, until you call `std::cin.clear()`. You're right Alex didn't explain this, see here for a full description http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istream/getline

Comment: @john - perfect, that's the answer that I was looking for ( eventually ).

Answer (score 11):

```
std::cin.getline(line, recordLen+1);
```

Here, if the input is longer than `recordLen` chars, the remaining characters will not be read and will remain in the stream. The next time you read from `cin`, you'll read those remaining characters. Note that, in this case, `cin` will raise its `failbit`, which is probably what you're experiencing.

If your first input is exactly `recordLen` chars long, only the newline will remain in the stream and the next call to `getline` will appear to read an empty string.

Other than that, `getline` does overwrite the buffer.

If you want to ignore anything beyond the first `recordLen` chars on the same line, you can call `istream::clear` to clear the `failbit` and `istream::ignore` to ignore the rest of the line, after `istream::getline`:

```
std::cin.getline(line, recordLen+1);
std::cin.clear();
std::cin.ignore( std::numeric_limits<streamsize>::max(), '\n' );
```

Comment: I print out what gets read from `cin` after that second call to `getline()`. Nothing gets output - it appears as though `getline()` read nothing.

Comment: you say that "Here if the input is longer than `recordLen` chars` ... the next time you read from `cin`, you'll read those remaining chars. The program *doesn't* appear to do this. Nothing gets displayed.

Comment: @BeeBand You need to call `clear()` before `ignore()` see comment above.